# How can I show data stored in a database with ajax - Laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

My route as below;

```
Route::post ('/sepetim', 'ShoppingCartController@addStock');
```

My controller as below;

```
public function addStock(Request $request) {
    $data = new ShoppingCartDetail();
    $data->cart_id = $request->input('cart_id');
    $data->stock_id = $request->input('stock_id');
    $data->price = 1;
    $data->save();
}
```

My ajax as below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/sepetim',
    data: {
        '_token': $('input[name="_token"]').val(),
        'name': $('input[name=name]').val(),
        'cart_id': $('input[name=cart_id]').val(),
        'stock_id': id
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // alert("Başarılı bir şekilde eklendi.");
    },
});
```

The div I want to update with Ajax.

```
@foreach($all_values_list as $row)
                        <div class="sepeturunalan row d-flex align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-1">
                                <img src="http://vomsis.com/uploads/thumb_{{$row['imageable_name']}}" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-12 pl">
                                <a href="#" title="">
                                    {{$row['stock_name']}}
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-2 text-center">
                                <span class="para">{{number_format($row['without_tax'] , '2' , ',' , '.')}}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-1 plr text-center">
                                <span class="para">{{number_format($row['new_price'] - $row['without_tax'] , '2' , ',' , '.')}} TL</span> <br/>
                                <span class="fw">(%{{$row['tax_ratio']}})</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-2 text-center">

                                <div class="input-group adet">

                                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                                          <button type="button" id="{{$row['id'].'u'}}" class="btn-number" onclick="buttons_click_minus({{$row['id']}})"  data-type="minus" data-field="quant[1]">
                                              <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                                          </button>
                                      </span>
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                                    {{ Form::hidden('cart_id', $cart_id) }}
                                    {{ Form::hidden('stock_id', $row['id']) }}
                                    <input type="text" id="{{$row['id']}}" name="name" class="input-number" onchange="input_onchange(this.id)" value="{{$row['quantity']}}" min="1" max="25">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                      <button type="button" type="submit" id="{{$row['id']}}" class="btn-number" onclick="buttons_click_plus(this.id)" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[1]">
                                          <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                      </button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-2 text-right">
                                <span class="para fw6">{{number_format($row['quantity'] * $row['new_price'] , '2' , ',' , '.')}} TL</span> <br/>
                                <span>
                                    {!! Form::open(['url' => '/sepetim/'.$cart_id .'/'.$row['id'], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
                                     <button type="submit" class="sepsil">
                                          <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Sil
                                     </button>
                                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                            </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
                                <p class="aciklama">
                                    <i class="fa fa-info-circle renk"></i>
                                    <span class="para">100TL </span> üzeri kargo bedava! kampanyasına dahil ürün
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            @endforeach
```

The above code is registering to the database. **My question**: How can I show data stored in a database with ajax - Laravel?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXtBv.png)

Ajax is working when button is clicked. Registering to the database. How can I show.

Comment: return view and show that response in some div  using .html()

Comment: where do you wan to display in a div ?

Comment: I add a picture to the question.

Answer (score 0):

After `$data->save();`, do something like `return response()->json(["data" => $data]);`, which passes `$data` to your `success: function(data)` as a `json` object available via `data.data`:

Controller Function (PHP):

```
public function  addStock(Request $request) {
  ...
  return response()->json(["data" => $data]);
}
```

Success Function (JS):

```
...
success: function(data) {
  console.log(data.data); // (May want to change your PHP return value to something other than data)
},
```

To actually display the returned `data` in your page, you would either need to return some HTML via the `addStock` method, or construct some HTML in your `success` function:

Controller Function (PHP)

```
public function addStock(Request $request){
  ...
  $renderedHtml = view("example")->with(["data" => $data])->render();
  return response()->json(["data" => $data, "renderedHtml" => $renderedHtml]);
}
```

Success Function (JS):

```
...
success: function(data) {
  $("#someDiv").html(data.renderedHtml);
  // OR
  var renderedHtml = "<div>";
  renderedHtml += "<span>$" + data.data.price + "</span>";
  // etc etc
  renderedHtml += "</div>";
  $("#someDiv").html(renderedHtml);
},
```

Comment: Try this: Copy the HTML you use in your `@foreach` loop (`<div class="sepeturunalan ...`, but don't copy the actual loop) into a `.blade.php` file ("example.blade.php"), then use `view("example")->with(["row" => $data])->render();` That will send the HTML back in your AJAX response, then add it to the DOM `.html()`, `.append()`, etc etc.